# Can not get the text in ContentControl in Word by usting Python-docx

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

[ContentControl Document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1heJYFTToMDQVEudd5oLvStk2TGTvA88b)

I am new to the Python and coding. New I have a problem and need your help.
I tried to read a docx document by using Python-docx, but all of the text I wanted were in the ContentControl. When I try to print the text of the paragraph with a ContentControl, error occurs.

For exemple, I try to print the 1st paragraphe, using

```
import docx
doc= docx.Document("C:\ContentControl.docx")
p=doc.paragraphs
print(p[0].text)
```

then I get an error like:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 8: illegal multibyte sequence
```

So what should I do to get the text in ContentControl?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I've added a sample document in the question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, with Python-docx.

If you check https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/oxml/text/paragraph.py – the code that reads paragraphs and their contents –, you can see that it only parses two sub-elements of `<w:p>`: its formatting from `<w:pPr>`, and its text runs from `<w:r>`. The contents of a text run is parsed with `text/run.py`, which iterates over its elements and stores data for `rPr` (local text run formatting), `t` (plain text itself), and `tab` (a literal Tab), and a handful more.

But Word's "contentControl" is stored in *another* tag, which is *not* parsed!

```
<w:p>  <!-- paragraph -->
  <w:r>  <!-- text runs -->
    <w:t>Editions&#160;:</w:t>  <!-- plain text -->
  </w:r>  <!-- end text run -->
  <w:sdt>
    <w:sdtPr>
    <w:sdtContent>   <!-- something else! -->
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Henry</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:sdtContent>
  </w:sdt>
  <w:r>  <!-- next text run; just a tab -->
    <w:tab/>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
  </w:r>  <!-- end of that text run -->
</w:p>
```

(from your sample document; some codes are elided for brevity)

As you can see, the ContentControl data is inside a `<w:sdt>` tag, which in turn is a direct descendent of `<w:p>`. So the code to read its data should be in `paragraph.py`, but it is not.

You can clone `python-docx` and add proper handling of `<w:sdt>` yourself (and [here](http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_sdt-1.html) is all information you need for that), but it just may be easier to use Word itself, and use a VBA macro to convert these to plain text.

---

By the way, your error code has nothing to do with this. The "offending" character is the non-breaking space in the "Editions" line, stored as `&#160;`. Your text decoder should really not have had any problem with it. The problem is likely caused by you using the `gbk` decoder instead of UTF-8. There are some Chinese characters in the document, but also written as decimal escaped Unicode characters; there are no non-ASCII characters.